# Кнопка «ОК» — переводить или нет? Если переводить, то как?

Tags: стилистика, переводы

Инструкции к игре:

> Нажимайте кнопку «ОК», если значения совпадают.

1. Можно ли кнопку «ОК» назвать каким-либо русским словом, только не слишком длинным? Слово «Совпадает» — длинное.
2. Нужно ли это менять? Я хочу, чтобы текст выглядел не как перевод, а как будто эта игра родилась на русском. Насколько «ОК» сейчас выглядит иностранным?

Answer (score 2):

Самое близкое значение - "Да". Если помните, "7 Волк" и "Кудос" использовали именно его. :) Но можно использовать и "Ок". Это слово уже стало общеупотребительным. И тот, для кого эта игра не первая, тут же поймёт, о чём идёт речь. Но это целиком ваше решение. Даже сами разработчики используют несколько вариантов в меню - "Ok, "Yes", "Confirm" и пр. Но всё может упираться в количество пикселей и используемые вами таблицы шрифтов .fnt.

Comment: Вы бы написали именно «Ок», а не «ОК»?

Comment: По-моему, русскими буквами в любом случае неправильно писать.

Comment: Это используется сейчас повсеместно. В электронной промышленности. Устойчивый варваризм. Так, что, думаю, что русскими буквами можно. Вспомним задорновское "Океюшки!" :)   Кнопку с русским написанием можно во множестве найти в Google. Но если есть сомнения, можно использовать и графическое изображение подтверждающей "галочки".

Comment: Вот ещё на что можно обратить внимание - написание слова прописными (заглавными) буквами принято и в иностранном и в русском вариантах. "ОК" и "OK". И они почти ничем не отличаются. А иногда и вообще используют один и тот же шрифт.

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого слова в русском, да и не нужно оно.
слишком разный смысл у этого ОК. "Согласен" - только одна из возможностей, далеко не самая распространенная.
Другие:"(Всё) хорошо", "Ладно", "Да", "Понял", "Принял", "Подтверждаю", "(Я) за".

Не надо переводить. Хотя когда-то в аналогичной ситуации я перевел именно как "ладно", но потом все равно исправил на ОК.

Answer (score 0):

1. Зависит от того, сколько вам знаков можно использовать. Варианты: **совпало, готово, есть, да**. Можно с восклицательным знаком на конце.
2. *Ок* - поймет любой и использовать его можно, но "русскости" это игре не добавит.

Answer (score 0):

Всем здравия!

Комментирую ответом!

Я считаю, что надо переводить словом "Да". Можно подумать, что кто-то будет думать - "Да" является отрицанием. Чем "Да" не устраивает аль совсем помешались на этих океях? Если подтверждаю - Да, а отрицаю - Нет. Тут вроде очевидно.

Всем благ!

Comment: Прошу простить меня за вынесение личного мнения, но сдержаться от ответа я не смог. Уж слишком болезненный вопрос!

Answer (score 0):

ОК переводить не стоит. Слово не русское, но оно крепко вошло в употребление и понятно всем.